# Prevent user from entering more characters into uitextview

Tags: ios7, xcode6, uitextview, edit

How could I prevent the user from entering any more characters into a uitextview after the textview has reached a given height? Here is the code I thought would work but does not. I can't put in any more characters but for some reason I can't even delete any..

```
   - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
    {

        if (textView.frame.size.height > 102)
        {
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
}
```

Any ideas? :(

Comment: You're being passed the text field so why are you referencing it (or a different one?) explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new string that matches what the edit would produce.  If the new string is shorter than the existing string, return `YES` also.

Example:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[textView text]];
    [string replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
    BOOL deleted = [string length] < [[textView text] length];
    if (deleted) {
        NSLog(@"Characters deleted");
        return YES;
    }
    if (textView.frame.size.height > 102)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand fully. Could you show it in some code or explain it in more detail?

Comment: Updated with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
    {

        NSLayoutManager* layoutManager = textView.layoutManager;
        NSTextContainer* textContainer = textView.textContainer;
        int glyphCount = layoutManager.numberOfGlyphs;
        if(text.length == 0) glyphCount--; //deleting

        CGRect textRect = [layoutManager boundingRectForGlyphRange:NSMakeRange(0, glyphCount) inTextContainer: textContainer];

        if (textRect.size.height > 102)
        {
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
}
```

Comment: No it does not unfortunately :(